# What to do when css3 not support in some older version

Tags: css, 3d, transform

I was coding with CSS3 but some older version of browsers like chrome 10 and more are not supporting this. I'm doing 3D transform. In which I'm rotating a button, Its not working in IE10 also and some older version of browsers. Is there any way to run it in all browser. I'm not too much familiar with javascript. Please help

Answer (score 0):

When you develop the UI you have to check browser requirements and make sure everything works in all the targeted browsers.

Unfortunately there is no magical potion for this, if you are developing for old browsers avoid CSS3, but in your case it is even not working with IE10.

I suggest you to create a new question and paste your code which doesn't work as an individual question so we will be able to help you.

You may be interested by libraries such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) but again, it depends what are your issues.

Comment: I saw that 3D transform is not supported in IE10. otherwise in all latest browser its working perfectly. Is there any javascript by which I can do this?? then give me links I have to study then

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/02/css3-3d-transforms-in-ie10.aspx) is a link.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options really, as there is no real way to make CSS3 work on browsers that don't support it (although perhaps CSS3 PIE might help http://css3pie.com/ a little).

The two methods you can choose are **graceful degradation** or **progressive enhancement**.

***Graceful degradation*** is basically using the best technology (CSS3) for the most up to date browsers, supporting the top level users and providing them with the best experience, however to provide users with less capabilities you can employ graceful degradation to slowly remove layers and effects that CSS3 can give you, whilst still providing a reasonable or similar level of functionality. You can do this by serving different style sheets to different browsers to match their capabilities and give them the best they can cope.

***Progressive enhancement*** is kind of the opposite of the above, and you start with a set level of standard that can be used by all browsers, and ensure all have a similar level of functionality, although this time you keep going back and finding ways of slowly incorporating different styles and properties to different style sheets for different browsers.

It doesn't really matter which you choose to do, although graceful degradation is more common nowadays as browsers ramp up compatibility and new tweaks come out.

For you I would suggest starting out with support for the higher end browsers and then peeling away the CSS as much as possible for the lower end browsers that cannot support all the functionality and then if you must, just drop support for those browsers or potentially look into other methods of animation/3d transformation (something I know little about) for those less capable versions of browsers.

Good luck!